# Return Single Field with Rails Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

I'm having trouble with something that should be so easy, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I'm simply trying to do a query that returns a single field instead of the complete record in Rails 3.

model method

```
def self.find_user_username(user_id)
  user_name = User.select("user_name").where(user_id)
  return user_name
end
```

I'm staring at the Rails Guide ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)
and it simply says (where viewable_by, locked = fields):

```
Client.select("viewable_by, locked")
```

I've tried flip flopping the select, like so:

```
User.select("user_name").where(user_id) - AND - 
User.where(user_id).select("user_name")
```

but neither work.  In fact, I even tried:

```
user_name = User.select("yoda").where(user_id)
```

and I didn't get an error.  When I look in the view, where I have:

```
Friend.find_user_username(friend.user_id)
```

I just keep getting the hash: ActiveRecord::Relation:0x2f4942f0

Comment: What happens when you do `user_name = User.select("user_name").where(user_id).first`?

Comment: I still just receive the hash

Comment: in Rails 6 you can used `pick(:id)`, which is like `pluck(:id).first`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

BTW if the question is about ActiveRecord::Relation it's the class of the object returned by where and select as it's said in the Rails Guide you're reading.
It's optimized to be chained between several methods and *you get the model object when you actually access an element* of the association (so behind the scenes the SQL query is run just one time). This means you get the Relation object because you just return it.

In this case maybe the best solution is just use find and the access the user_name attribute

```
def self.find_user_username(user_id)
  User.find(user_id).user_name
end
```

The query will get all the other attributes from the DB but you'll return just the username.

Comment: This will fetch the whole row of the database and rails will instantiate the full model object - if you really just want the name, it's much more efficient to use `pluck` or `first`, as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 31):

```
User.where(:id => user_id).pluck(:user_name).first
```

Should do what you're trying to do.

[pluck](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) "accepts a column name as argument and returns an array of values of the specified column with the corresponding data type"

Comment: This won't work. `find` returns an `ActiveRecord::Base`, not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, and that's where `pluck` and `first` are defined.

Comment: You're right, thanks, I've fixed the code though I'm wondering if the best thing to do is just return User.find(user_id).user_name...

Comment: I'd probably use something like this if I had a query that I executed a lot and either (1) returned many, many rows, or (2) returned rows with a lot of columns that I didn't care about. That would reduce the amount of data returned from the database, which would presumably speed things up. But I agree with you in the general case.

Comment: when i did this, i received the error "undefined method `pluck' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x17c155c8>".  i'm using 3.0, maybe it's a method introduced in 3.1 or 3.2?

Comment: @yellowreign as Brandan said pluck method is defined in ActiveRecord::Relation while find returns a ActiveRecord::Base object. I've edited the comment accordingly.

Comment: `pluck` was introduced in Rails 3.2.

Comment: I would add a `.limit(1)` to this query after the `where` otherwise you are going to pull all the results from the database into memory.

Comment: No real need for the limit 1 because there's really a very small chance the id field query would return more than one record anyway.

Comment: The `.first` already does a limit(1). There is also a big different from using `.first` or `.limit(1)` - 
`.first` will give you a **single record**. 
`.limit(1)` will give you an **array with 1 entry**.

Comment: @OskarHolmkratz In the code above, `.first` _does not_ do a `limit(1)`, because it's not the `ActiveRelation#first` method being called, it's `Array#first` being called. `ActiveRelation#pluck` returns an array (not another `ActiveRelation` object). If you were calling `ActiveRelation#first`, then yes, it'd do a `limit(1)`. If you really wanted that in the example above, you'd need `User.where(:id => user_id).limit(1).pluck(:user_name).first`.

Answer (score 9):

Rails 6 introduced `ActiveRecord::Relation#pick`.

`pick(:foo)` is equivalent to `limit(1).pluck(:foo).first`.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people referring to `.pluck`. It does have a caveat, it returns an array of the columns for records found.

If column is unique, like `id`, it's not an issue, DB will send to Active Record same content, 1 record 1 column, using `limit(1)` or not (using it is useless, and most certainly it will be discarded by DB query optimizer).

But if column is not unique, it could in fact be not the best performance. Because, `first` is called after AR executes DB query, returning `[0]` of all the results brought from DB. `limit`, is called before that execution and it's sent to DB as part of the query., filtering the results.

Consider the following table and setup:

```
> Log
=> Log(id: integer, user_id, integer, event_type: integer, timestamp: datetime)

> user_newest_logs = Log.where(user_id: 1).order(timestamp: :desc)
```

Now, let's get the last event date time for the user_id = 1:

1) this is the nicest way. DB returns one record with 1 column for timestamp

```
> user_newest_logs.limit(1).pluck(:timestamp).first
SELECT timestamp FROM logs WHERE logs.user_id = 1 ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
=> Fri, 09 Aug 2019 23:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

2) DB returns one record with all columns

```
> user_newest_logs.first
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE logs.user_id = 1 ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Log:0x00111111>
 id: 920821839,
 user_id: 1,
 event_type: 1,
 timestamp: Fri, 09 Aug 2019 23:00:00 UTC +00:00

> user_newest_logs.first.timestamp
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE logs.user_id = 1 ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
=> Fri, 09 Aug 2019 23:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

3) DB returns the list of timestamps for N records

```
> user_newest_logs.pluck(:timestamp)
SELECT timestamp FROM logs WHERE logs.user_id = 1 ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC
=> [Fri, 09 Aug 2019 23:00:00 UTC +00:00,
Fri, 09 Aug 2019 22:00:00 UTC +00:00,
Fri, 09 Aug 2019 21:00:00 UTC +00:00,
Fri, 09 Aug 2019 20:00:00 UTC +00:00,
...
]

> user_newest_logs.pluck(:timestamp).first
SELECT timestamp FROM logs WHERE logs.user_id = 1 ORDER BY logs.timestamp DESC
=> Fri, 09 Aug 2019 23:00:00 UTC +00:00

> user_newest_logs.pluck(:timestamp).count    # NOT PRETTY HUH?!
=> 1523
```

So, if you do `pluck(:column).first` can be actually worst than just `find_by.column`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.first` to force the query to return a record because a `where` only returns an activerecord relation.

```
1.9.3p0 :048 > user = User.select('first_name').where('id = 1').first
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT first_name FROM `users` WHERE (id = 1) LIMIT 1
+------------+
| first_name |
+------------+
| Johnny     |
+------------+
1 row in set

1.9.3p0 :049 > user.first_name
=> "Johnny"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the `select`, it's the `where`. Your condition right now is essentially `WHERE #{user_id}`. If you executed this on the Rails console, you'd see something like this:

```
1.9.2p290 :003 > puts User.select('user_name').where(1).to_sql
SELECT user_name FROM "users" WHERE (1)
```

You need to pass the conditions as a hash to `where`, and take the first record as others suggested:

```
User.select('user_name').where(:id => user_id).first
```

Comment: for some reason, this still resulted in returning the whole record for me.  User.find(user_id).username, seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that while not returning every field the query does return an object rather than the specific field's value. You can change the return of `return user_name` to `return user_name.user_name`.

```
def self.find_user_username(user_id)
  user_name = User.select("user_name").where(user_id)
  return user_name
end
```

Or you might see if `User.user_name.where(user_id).first` does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method called 'pluck' refer http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck